# Why is MongoDB supposed to Consistent & Partition tolerant but not Available

Tags: mongodb

Why is MongoDB supposed to Consistent & Partition tolerant but not Available? According to CAP theorem a CP system is one which is not always available but having a replica set does ensure high availability. Higher the number of nodes in a replica set , the system becomes more available. Then why is the MongoDB supposedly only CP?

Comment: The previous question does not have an answer to my current question. My question is why is MongoDB not considered highly available?

Comment: Like the answer says, by default all reads go to the primary so if it's down MongoDB is not available.

Comment: Yes , if a primary goes down then a failover will happen and one of the secondaries will tend to become a primary and continue to serve data? Where is availability compromised??

Comment: That's a question that's specific enough to not be a duplicate.  The short answer is because the system is unavailable during the failover.  http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/replica-sets/#how-long-does-replica-set-failover-take